# Jest crashes by running tests located in the fastclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, fastclick.js

This project was started with Create React App.
But added enzyme and FastClick when running yarn test in crashed.
Below are detail messages.
Thanks for any help.

Repro download : https://github.com/zhengjin/react-framework

Run npx envinfo --preset jest:

```sh
System:
   OS: macOS 10.14.5
   CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
 Binaries:
   Node: 10.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node
   Yarn: 1.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/yarn
   npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/npm
 npmPackages:
   jest: 23.6.0 => 23.6.0
```

Run yarn test: Error Messages
TypeError: _fastclick.default.attach is not a function

```
 61 |     this.entryBurry();
  62 |       console.log(FastClick)
> 63 |     FastClick.attach(document.body);
     |               ^
  64 |     console.log(queryString.parse(window.location.search));
  65 |     let json = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
  66 |     this.loadLocales();

  at Download.attach [as componentWillMount] (src/pages/download/download.js:63:15)
  at ReactShallowRenderer._mountClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:796:26)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:738:14)
  at render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:666:53)
  at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
  at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:666:18)
  at new render (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:397:22)
  at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
  at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/pages/download/index.test.js:14:23)
```

Comment: Can you check to see if `action` is indeed defined as a function, or if you are missing something.

Comment: If run yarn start, it will be render well.